# PHP Newbie problem - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Tags: php

New to php, doing a tutorial to use php on the server side to connect to flex. I have typed in the code for the video tutorial below but i can't seem to get it to work for me. The plan is put longitude and latitude data from the SQL database, format it as xml and pull it into flex The php code is as follows

```
<?PHP

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("demo");

$result = mysql_query("select * from maps");

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><map>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<loc><lat>" . $row["lat"] . "</lat>";
    echo "<lon>" . $row["lon"] . "</lon>";
    echo "<name>" . $row["name"] . "</name></loc>";
}

echo "</map>";

?>
```

And the error I receive is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in C:\wamp\www\Afghan_Mapping-debug\map.php on line 10

I have checked and double checked for open brackets or quotes but can't see any. I'm using WAMP.

If anyone can make any sense of it I'd appreciate it,

Thanks

Comment: what is the actual line associated with the line identified in the error?

Comment: Hey, thanks for coming back, its line 10, the start of the while loop

Comment: I can't tell if it's the posts formatting, but could it be the way it's interpreting the line before it: echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><map>";

Comment: Spot on! Good shout lad. I reduced that line to 
echo "<?xml ?><map>";
and it works like a charm, thanks again

Comment: let me add an answer so I can get the credit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell if it's the posts formatting, but could it be the way it's interpreting the line before it: echo "";

Typically, the line number the error is associated with is often the line/statement after where the real error is, because when it get's line 10, it realizes somethings not right based on what it just interpreted from the previous line.  Funny, but that's how I've noticed it goes.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(.$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

should be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

(without the dot)

Comment: hey, 
thanks, for coming back, I shouldn't have had the dot in my question. It was in error. I have corrected the code in the question, The code that is now above does not work.

I'm afraid i had been reaching at straws!

Answer (score 0):

try using a foreach instead of while:

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

```
foreach($row as $r)
{
    echo "<loc><lat>" . $r["lat"] . "</lat>";
    echo "<lon>" . $r["lon"] . "</lon>";
    echo "<name>" . $r["name"] . "</name></loc>";
}
```

Comment: Hey, 
Thanks for you help.

I tried that and the error remains the same, at the same line

Comment: Line 10 is
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: Hi Wilson, 
I gave wamp a refresh and I now recieve and answer. Its not what I was expecting, but let me dig into what the for loop is giving me.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: I've linked to a pic of my database. [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/375122/php2.png) The result I receive from the for loop is "111333666QQQ"
So the foreach is iterating around the first record, again and again, but only returning the first number or letter

Comment: Hi Wilson, it was actually a problem with xml declaration above, I assume how i was trying to escape the quotes, 

Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I'm able to get this code to parse without any issue.